# Write POST received data into json file in json format

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post

Trying to add data that was received with POST request into json file in this format :

```
[ {
    "id": 1,
    "data": "hello",
    "data1": "hi",
    "data2": "hey",
} ]
```

but right now it writes like this :

```
id=1&data=hello&data1=hi&data2=hey
```

I've read that i have to parse the data first, here is the code :

```
if (request.method == 'POST' && request.url == "/page") {
        var body = "";
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function (req, res) {

        POST = qs.parse(body);
        console.log(POST);

        var operation = POST.insert;

        if (operation == 'insert') {
            fs.readFile("file.json", "utf8", function (err, data){
                var updateData =  {
                    id: POST.id,
                    data: POST.data,
                    data1: POST.data1,
                    data2: POST.data2
                }

                var newData = qs.stringify(updateData);
                fs.writeFile('file.json', newData, "utf8");
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    });
}
```

How to convert it into json format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `qs.stringify` is to take an object and turn it into a query string.

If you want JSON and not a query string, then don't use that function!

You can convert an object into JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped !